# Probability that a "sequential average" is equal to arithmetic average

Tags: statistics

Suppose a student will take five quizzes in the course of the semester.  The student's grade will be determined by the arithmetic average of his/her quiz scores.  On each of the five 2-point quizzes, the student will either get 1 point (with probability 1/3) or 2 points (with probability 2/3).  Define the ``sequential average" of the first $k$ quiz scores to be the arithmetic average of {the $k$th quiz score, the arithmetic average of the first $k-1$ quiz scores} (i.e. $(a_k+(a_1+...a_{k-1})/(k-1))/2$ where $a_i$ is the score on the $i$th quiz).  What is the probability the sequential average of the student's first 5 quiz scores is equal to the arithmetic average of the first 5 quiz scores?

I recognize that I could look at all 32 possibilities for the student's 5 quiz scores and determine when the sequential average equals the arithmetic average, and then compute the probabilities of those particular states occurring.  However, I am looking for the most efficient way to approach the problem, ideally a method that is just as easily applicable to a generalization where the student takes $N$ quizzes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You want the probability that:

$$\frac{a_5}{2}+\frac{\sum_1^4 a_i}{8} = \frac{\sum_1^5 a_i}{5}$$

Simplifying the left hand side, we get:

$$\frac{4a_5+\sum_1^4 a_i}{8} = \frac{\sum_1^5 a_i}{5} \implies 20a_5+5\sum_1^4 a_i = 8\sum_1^5 a_i = 8 a_5 + 8\sum_1^4 a_i \implies$$

$$12 a_5 = 3\sum_1^4 a_i \implies a_5 = \frac{1}{4}\sum_1^4 a_i$$

So, you want the probability that the fifth test score is equal to the average of the previous four test scores.

However, $a_k \in \{1,2\}$ so you really need to know the probability that the mean of the first four tests equals 1 or 2 and treat this average as independent of the final test.